# Prism not navigating to page when await-able method before navigation

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I'm using `Xamarin.Forms 4.4.0.9916` and `Prism.Unity.Forms 7.2.0.1422`

In a basic prism application, I would like to perform a task before navigating to the `MainPage` (for the example I replace the task with `await Task.Delay(500);`)

The problem is that the app doesn't navigate to `MainPage`.
If I comment out the `await Task.Delay(500);` then the app navigates to the `MainPage`

So, what is the problem with that code? How can I have an awaitable method before navigating to the MainPage?

When the `await Task.Delay(x);` is fast (i.e. `await Task.Delay(50);`) then the app navigates to the `MainPage`

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    public App() : this(null) { }
    public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer) { }

    protected override async void OnInitialized()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        await Task.Delay(500);

        await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(new Uri("http://www.somewhere.com/MainPage", UriKind.Absolute));
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage, MainPageViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one way of doing things here however what you will want to implement is some sort of LoadingPage. This can be a rather "Dumb" Page if needed (without a ViewModel). Alternatively you can migrate your startup logic into the LoadingPageViewModel and then Navigate from there.

```cs
protected override async void OnInitialized()
{
    // This ensures the MainPage is set and prevents the app from being killed
    // by the platform. Also provides better User Experience...
    await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/LoadingPage");
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/MainPage");
}
```

Comment: I can see the benefit of having a "LoadingPage" before navigating to the "MainPage" as you explained in your comment. But, out of curiosity, why the navigation doesn't work properly without this "LoadingPage"?

Comment: you haven't told me what your "problem" is or provided a reproduction so I can't really tell you why you might be experiencing a specific issue. That said I can tell you that the platforms, especially iOS will terminate your app if you do not set the Application.MainPage fast enough which is why you would want to have some sort of Loading Page before doing anything that is actually async.

Comment: In the place of `Task.Delay` I have an `async` method that assess if an authentication token is valid or not. If the token is valid then I navigate to MainPage, if the token is not valid then I navigate to LoginPage. I'm testing the app for the moment in Android. The behavior of the app is not termination. It's just an empty page with only the status bar available. I have created just an empty app with a `Task.Delay` before the navigation just to eliminate other factors. Seems that below 100 in `Delay` will navigate to MainPage.